# Como popular imagens ListView com Ascync firemonkey android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Consigo popular o *ListView* com a função abaixo, porém popular as imagens causa pequenos travamentos, pesquisei um pouco e achei sugestões do uso de *Threads com Async*, mas não consegui aplicar ao meu projeto.

Minha duvida é: Como popular as imagens de forma fluída, primeiro populando os textos, e as imagens conforme forem carregadas?

```
ListView1.BeginUpdate;
while not qrycliente.Eof do
begin
  ////carrega imagem
  stm:= qrycliente.CreateBlobStream(qrycliente.FieldByName('IMAGEM'), bmRead);

  if stm.Size > 0 then
  begin

    try
      img := TBitmap.Create;
      img.LoadFromStream(Stm);
      try
        rr_imagem.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.Assign(img);
        inicial:= '';
      except
        inicial:= Copy(qrycliente.FieldByName('CLIENTE').AsString, 0, 1);
      end;
    finally
      Stm.Free;
      img.Free;
    end;

  end
  else
  begin
    inicial:= Copy(qrycliente.FieldByName('CLIENTE').AsString, 0, 1);
  end;
  ////

  LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  LItem.Detail := IntToStr(qrycliente.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);
  LItem.Data['nome']:= qrycliente.FieldByName('CLIENTE').AsString;
  LItem.Data['fantasia']:= qrycliente.FieldByName('FANTASIA').AsString;

  LItem.Data['endereco']:= qrycliente.FieldByName('ENDERECO').AsString+','+
                           qrycliente.FieldByName('NUMERO').AsString;

  LItem.Data['bairro_cidade']:= qrycliente.FieldByName('BAIRRO').AsString+','+
                                qrycliente.FieldByName('CIDADE').AsString;

  LItem.Data['telefone']:= qrycliente.FieldByName('TELEFONE').AsString+' / '+
                           qrycliente.FieldByName('TELEFONE2').AsString+' / '+
                           qrycliente.FieldByName('CELULAR').AsString;

  LItem.Data['letra']:= inicial;

  LItem.Data['imagem']:= rr_imagem.MakeScreenshot;

  qrycliente.Next;
end;
ListView1.EndUpdate;
```